# Rails Simple Form custom collection for select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

Is there a way to have different value for label in select box in Simple Form with custom Collection?

Below is an example that I have:

```
= f.input :hall_type, collection: ["Main", "Exhibition", "Conference", {"KnowedgeLibrary" => "Knowedge Library"}], prompt: "Choose a hall type"
```

I want `KnowledgeLibrary` to be value and `Knowledge Library` to be the label/text of the option

Answer (score 1):

here is the syntax

```
:collection => [['label1', 'value1'], ['label2', 'value2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

`= f.select :hall_type, options_for_select(["Main", "Exhibition", "Conference", ["Knowedge Library", "KnowedgeLibrary"]], "KnowedgeLibrary"), {prompt: "Choose a hall type"}`